# Question about orthogonal transformation / orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, orthonormal

I have a question about orthogonal transformations.

If $T$ is an orthogonal transformation from $V$ to $V$, should the representation matrix with respect to any orthonormal basis of any inner product be an orthogonal matrix?

I'll be more specific, I was given $Tu=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}u$, $T: \mathbb R^{2} -> \mathbb R^{2}$ and I was asked is there an inner product where this transformation is orthogonal.

What I want to say is, since the standard basis is orthonormal with respect to the standard inner product (dot product), and the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to that basis is not orthogonal, then the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to ANY orthonormal basis (not necesarily with respect to the regular inner product) is not orthogonal.

Is it correct to say such a thing?

Comment: Yes, I can see why the question is equivalent to what you wrote, but I can't see why this fails here.

Comment: Why? $STS^{-1}$ could have column vectors that are orthonormal basis but $STS^{-1}$ is not diagonal matrix. for example $STS^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 6 \\ -3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Could there be an orthogonal linear transformation $T$, and an orthonormal basis $B$ with respect to an inner product $@$ such that $[T]_B$ is not an orthogonal matrix?

Comment: Julien, please take a look at what I wrote on the comment above yours. I would love to know the answer for that question.

Comment: About your comment. If you consider the same inner product, any change of orthonormal basis will leave the matrix orthogonal. If you are considering a new inner product and the new matrix in an orthonormal basis for the new inner product, it need not be orthogonal anymore. Note that a matrix is "orthogonal" iff it is an isometry for the canonical inner product.

Comment: To summarize, the question amounts to: is $T$ similar to an orthogonal matrix? Given that the spectrum of $T$ is $\{1\}$, it would have to be similar to an orthogonal matrix with $1$ as only eigenvalue. What would that force $T$ to be?